# UICollectionView Set number of columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just started learning about UICollectionViews. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to specify the number of columns in a collectionview. The default is set to 3 (iPhone/portrait). I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to find a concise answer.

Comment: I have an app that I use `UICollectionView` basically as a grid because I know I only want 4 columns. I do this by making my cells a certain size, and the spacing between them a certain size so the collectionview only shows 4 columns, no matter what orientation. Is this similar to what you need?

Comment: Or is it more of a general question, like can I dynamically set the number of columns or not?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to have 7 columns in portrait mode. So I've made the width of the columns 46px (320 px / 46px = 7). I didn't know their was a spacing property.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

CollectionViews are very powerful, and they come at a price. Lots, and lots of options. As omz said:

> there are multiple ways you could change the number of columns

I'd suggest implementing the [`<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol, giving you access to the following methods in which you can have greater control over the layout of your `UICollectionView`, without the need for subclassing it:

- `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:`
- `collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:`
- `collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:`
- `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection:`
- `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:`
- `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

Also, implementing the following method will force your UICollectionView to update it's layout on an orientation change: (say you wanted to re-size the cells for landscape and make them stretch)

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Additionally, here are 2 really good tutorials on `UICollectionViews`:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Comment: Will this work for all iOS devices? Should `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` be handled for all devices seperately?

Comment: @Sharath, of course that works for everything. You just need to do your math in a way that's adaptable for all devices ;). Adaptive design.

Comment: wow so great, but real example? in Android we can do `new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4))` (4 columns), very easy, or just use `LinearLayoutManager` (it of course has only 1 column)

Answer (score 178):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12.3, you can use one the **4 following implementations** in order to set the number of items per row in your `UICollectionView` while managing insets and size changes (including rotation).

---

#### #1. Subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s [`itemSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617711-itemsize) property

*ColumnFlowLayout.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class ColumnFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    let cellsPerRow: Int

    init(cellsPerRow: Int, minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 0, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRow
        super.init()

        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
        self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
        self.sectionInset = sectionInset
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        let marginsAndInsets = sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

    override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
        let context = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds) as! UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext
        context.invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics = newBounds.size != collectionView?.bounds.size
        return context
    }

}
```

*CollectionViewController.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let columnLayout = ColumnFlowLayout(
        cellsPerRow: 5,
        minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
        minimumLineSpacing: 10,
        sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 59
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

---

#### #2. Using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s [`itemSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617711-itemsize) method

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let margin: CGFloat = 10
    let cellsPerRow = 5

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView, let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = margin
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin)

        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView, let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
        let marginsAndInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        flowLayout.itemSize =  CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 59
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

}
```

---

#### #3. Using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`'s [`collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) method

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let inset: CGFloat = 10
    let minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    let minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    let cellsPerRow = 5

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: inset, left: inset, bottom: inset, right: inset)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return minimumLineSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return minimumInteritemSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let marginsAndInsets = inset * 2 + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 59
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

}
```

---

#### #4. Subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s [`estimatedItemSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617709-estimateditemsize) property

*CollectionViewController.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let items = [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.",
        "Lorem ipsum.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.",
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur."
    ]

    let columnLayout = FlowLayout(
        cellsPerRow: 3,
        minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
        minimumLineSpacing: 10,
        sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView?.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

}
```

*FlowLayout.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    let cellsPerRow: Int

    required init(cellsPerRow: Int = 1, minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 0, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRow

        super.init()

        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
        self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
        self.sectionInset = sectionInset
        estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return layoutAttributes }

        let marginsAndInsets = collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        layoutAttributes.bounds.size.width = ((collectionView.bounds.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let superLayoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
        guard scrollDirection == .vertical else { return superLayoutAttributes }

        let layoutAttributes = superLayoutAttributes.compactMap { layoutAttribute in
            return layoutAttribute.representedElementCategory == .cell ? layoutAttributesForItem(at: layoutAttribute.indexPath) : layoutAttribute
        }

        // (optional) Uncomment to top align cells that are on the same line
        /*
        let cellAttributes = layoutAttributes.filter({ $0.representedElementCategory == .cell })
        for (_, attributes) in Dictionary(grouping: cellAttributes, by: { ($0.center.y / 10).rounded(.up) * 10 }) {
            guard let max = attributes.max(by: { $0.size.height < $1.size.height }) else { continue }
            for attribute in attributes where attribute.size.height != max.size.height {
                attribute.frame.origin.y = max.frame.origin.y
            }
        }
         */

        // (optional) Uncomment to bottom align cells that are on the same line
        /*
        let cellAttributes = layoutAttributes.filter({ $0.representedElementCategory == .cell })
        for (_, attributes) in Dictionary(grouping: cellAttributes, by: { ($0.center.y / 10).rounded(.up) * 10 }) {
            guard let max = attributes.max(by: { $0.size.height < $1.size.height }) else { continue }
            for attribute in attributes where attribute.size.height != max.size.height {
                attribute.frame.origin.y += max.frame.maxY - attribute.frame.maxY
            }
        }
         */

        return layoutAttributes
    }

}
```

*Cell.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundColor = .orange
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.bounds.size.width
        layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return layoutAttributes
    }

    // Alternative implementation
    /*
    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = layoutAttributes.size.width - contentView.layoutMargins.left - contentView.layoutMargins.right
        layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        return layoutAttributes
    }
    */

}
```

[image]

Comment: The solutions that use "viewWillTransition(to size ..." don't handle device rotation properly. Since it's called before the frame is set, the old dimension of the collectionView is used to calculate the cell size. (Haven't tried the other solutions yet)

Comment: This is awesome, #1 is great. Found better results regarding orientation changes by assigning `itemSize` a value in the `prepare()` override function. Also, adding `@IBInspectable` for the properties make it storyboard friendly.

Comment: `UICollectionView_p1_Swift[5166:81058] Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x105f98a18) to 'UICollectionView_p1_Swift.GalleryItemCollectionViewCell' (0x103316180).`

Comment: Wonderful answer! Chosen #4 to support constraints-based sizing. Special thanks for optional aligning snippets - that's what I need.

Comment: @Imanou Nice solution!! I'm using solution#1. Btw my minimum os is still 10.0. What is the equivalent of "collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always". in iOS 10?

Comment: How can get UICollectionView's height on Soluction #1

Comment: If you are not seeing any layout changes with #2 or #3 your may have to set `collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` first.

Comment: For #4 in my Cell, I needed to determine height like this `layoutAttributes.bounds.size.height = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow).height` as the layoutAttributes contained already the right width, so I marked this as required to get to the right height.

Comment: #4 I got issues with large navigation bar titles. Found out that it forgot the latest size estimates when scrolled to top. 
Fixed it by setting `itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` and giving `estimatedItemSize` an appropriate estimate. With your solution iOS tried to use 50pt as estimate height and decided to dequeue a lot of cells unnecessarily while scrolling to the top.

Comment: I use solution #1 and it is very easy and helpful for me, but I'm stuck at the point, I'm showing 3 cells in each row and spacing is managed in portrait mode of iPAD, but in landscape mode spacing between cells is very much, So please help that How I can manage it.???

Comment: The latest solution causes too many cells to be loaded into the view hierarchy. The `layoutAttributesForElements` gets called, and doesn't know about any correct dimensions yet.

Comment: Too many cells are loaded in because of the estimate size not being correct. If you want to have your cells get dequeued more efficiently, make sure to set a desires estimated item size.

Answer (score 63):

I implemented `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` on my `UICollectionViewController` and override the method responsible for determining the size of the Cell. I then took the screen width and divided it with my column requirement. For example, I wanted to have 3 columns on each screen size. So here's what my code looks like -

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 3.0; //Replace the divisor with the column count requirement. Make sure to have it in float.
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: You should make sure to have item spacing set to 0 to avoid having n-1 highly spaced items per row instead.

Answer (score 44):

Expanding on noob's answer:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
            + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
            + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow - 1))
        let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow))
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

This allows for any spacing between the cells. It assumes an `Int` member variable called `numberOfItemsPerRow` and also that all the cells are square and the same size.  As noted in jhilgert00's answer we must also react to orientation changes, but now by using `viewWillTransitionToSize` as `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is depreciated.

Comment: let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(numberOfItemsPerRow)) - you should remove casting to Int, because in some cases it make small spaces between cells

Answer (score 19):

Here is the working code for Swift 3 or above, to have a two-columns layout :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let nbCol = 2
    
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(nbCol - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(nbCol))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Feel free to change "nbCol" to your desired number of columns.

Comment: whats wrong with every solution when the insets are (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0), the layout becomes 1 column in this case!

Comment: @fraxool Great answer, but if I flip device the layout resets... Any fix for that?

Answer (score 18):

**Updated to  Swift 5+ iOS 13+**

Collectionview Estimate Size must be **none**

[image]

Declare margin for cell

```
let margin: CGFloat = 10
```

In viewDidLoad configure `minimumInteritemSpacing`, `minimumLineSpacing`, `sectionInset`

```
 guard let collectionView = docsColl, let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
    
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = margin
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin)
```

**UICollectionViewDataSource** method `sizeForItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let noOfCellsInRow = 2   //number of column you want
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))
    
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Updated to Swift 3:**

Instead of the flow layout, I prefer using custom layout for specific column number and row number. Because:

1. It can be dragged horizontally if column number is very big.
2. It is more acceptable logically because of using column and row.

**Normal cell and Header cell: (Add UILabel as a IBOutlet to your xib):**

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
}
}

class CollectionViewHeadCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
}
}
```

**Custom layout:**

```
let cellHeight: CGFloat = 100
let cellWidth: CGFloat = 100

class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    private var numberOfColumns: Int!
    private var numberOfRows: Int!

    // It is two dimension array of itemAttributes
    private var itemAttributes = [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()
    // It is one dimension of itemAttributes
    private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

override func prepare() {
    if self.cache.isEmpty {

        self.numberOfColumns = self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        self.numberOfRows = self.collectionView?.numberOfSections

        // Dynamically change cellWidth if total cell width is smaller than whole bounds
        /* if (self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns) > cellWidth {
         self.cellWidth = (self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width)!/CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns)
         }
         */
        for row in 0..<self.numberOfRows {
            var row_temp = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
            for column in 0..<self.numberOfColumns {

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: column, section: row)

                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath as IndexPath)
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: cellWidth*CGFloat(column), y: cellHeight*CGFloat(row), width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)

                row_temp.append(attributes)

                self.cache.append(attributes)
            }
            self.itemAttributes.append(row_temp)
        }
    }
}
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns)*cellWidth, height: CGFloat(self.numberOfRows)*cellHeight)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}
}
```

**CollectionView:**

```
let CellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
let HeadCellIdentifier = "HeadCellIdentifier"

class CollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

init() {
    let layout = CustomCollectionViewLayout()

    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    self.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    self.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewHeadCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HeadCellIdentifier)

    self.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func updateCollectionView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: CollectionView datasource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 20
}
override func numberOfItems(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let column = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section

    if column == 0 {
        let cell : CollectionViewHeadCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HeadCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewHeadCell

        cell.label.text = "\(row)"

        return cell
    }
    else if row == 0 {
        let cell : CollectionViewHeadCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HeadCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewHeadCell

        cell.label.text = "\(column)"

        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.label.text = String(format: "%d", arguments: [indexPath.section*indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: CollectionView delegate
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let column = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section

    print("\(column)  \(row)")
}
}
```

**Use CollectionView from ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let collectionView = CollectionView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView": collectionView]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView": collectionView]))
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    collectionView.updateCollectionView()
}
}
```

**Finally you can have fancy CollectionView!**

[image]

Comment: the problem with taking this solution is your static height and width

Comment: @rd_Custom layout means you can do what ever you want to do! My code is just showing the simplest case......

Answer (score 9):

If you are lazy using delegate.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func setItemsInRow(items: Int) {
        if let layout = self.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let contentInset = self.contentInset
            let itemsInRow: CGFloat = CGFloat(items);
            let innerSpace = layout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (itemsInRow - 1.0)
            let insetSpace = contentInset.left + contentInset.right + layout.sectionInset.left + layout.sectionInset.right
            let width = floor((CGRectGetWidth(frame) - insetSpace - innerSpace) / itemsInRow);
            layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)
        }
    }
}
```

*PS: Should be called after rotation too*

Comment: It works in Swift 4.0 too... after changes last two line:

let width = floor((frame.width - insetSpace - innerSpace) / itemsInRow)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)

Answer (score 7):

Because `UICollectionView` is so flexible, there are multiple ways you could change the number of columns, depending on the kind of layout you use.

The `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (which is probably what you're working with) doesn't specify a number of columns directly (because it depends on the view size/orientation). The easiest way to change it would be to set the `itemSize` property and/or `minimumInteritemSpacing`/`minimumLineSpacing`.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0. Works for both horizontal and vertical scroll directions and variable spacing**

Specify number of columns

```
let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3
```

Configure `flowLayout` to render specified `numberOfColumns`

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let horizontalSpacing = flowLayout.scrollDirection == .vertical ? flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing : flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    let cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.width - max(0, numberOfColumns - 1)*horizontalSpacing)/numberOfColumns
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```

Comment: All those long answer everywhere and this works with 5 lines of code :)

Comment: Good attempt. But this will not work if you use a sectionInset on the collectionViewLayout. To fix this, (1) calculate the available width by taking the cell width and subtracting flowLayout.sectionInset.left and flowLayout.sectionInset.right from it. (2) Where you calculate the cellWidth, replace 'view.frame.width' with the value calculated at (1).  Also, remember that the view's frame will only be finalized after loading, and can change, so you'll have to rebuild layout as needed.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for swift 3.0 -->

first conform to the protocol :

```
 UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

then add these methods :

```
    //this method is for the size of items      
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width/3
        let height : CGFloat = 160.0
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    //these methods are to configure the spacing between items

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First add **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** as protocol.

Then:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
        var columnCount = 3
        let width  = (view.frame.width - 20) / columnCount
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its all about layout you want to draw. You can create custom class inheriting from UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Currently there is not any direct method to set columns. If you want to achieve this kind of functionality you need to do it manually. You need to handle it in your custom flow layout class.

Now question will arise how you will do it? If you dont want to disturb cell frame you can adjust

```
 collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
 collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Another way is provide you own positions of cells. By overriding below two methods, which will get called during your layout formation.

```
  - (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
  - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
```

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes is class which will deal with cell position, frame, Zindex etc

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to append to Imanou Petit's answer #2.  To ensure margins are exact regardless of screen width, I use an iterative solver with a desired margin, and the # of columns as inputs.  I also added a directional flag on where their final margins will be compared to their target.

The iterative solver is shown below and returns cellWidth and margin.

```
private func iterativeCellSpacing(targetMargins : CGFloat,
                                  cellsPerRow : Int,
                                  isMinTarget : Bool) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat)
{
    var w : CGFloat = 0
    var m : CGFloat = targetMargins
    let cols : CGFloat = CGFloat(cellsPerRow)

    let numMargins : CGFloat = cols + 1.0
    let screenWidth : CGFloat = collectionView!.bounds.size.width


    var delta = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    while abs(delta) > 0.001
    {
        let totalMarginSpacing = numMargins * m
        let totalCellSpacing = screenWidth - totalMarginSpacing

        if (isMinTarget)
        {
            w = floor(totalCellSpacing / cols)
            m = ceil((screenWidth - cols * w) / numMargins)
        }
        else
        {
            w = ceil(totalCellSpacing / cols)
            m = floor((screenWidth - cols * w) / numMargins)
        }

        delta = screenWidth - w * CGFloat(cellsPerRow) - m * numMargins
    }

    return (w, m)
}
```

I call it as such:

```
fileprivate var margin: CGFloat = 20
fileprivate var cellWidth : CGFloat = 80
fileprivate let cellsPerRow = 4

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    (cellWidth, margin) = iterativeCellSpacing(targetMargins: margin, cellsPerRow: 4, isMinTarget: true)
    ...
}
```

I then apply the cellWidth and margin values to the flow layout as such:

```
extension MyCollectionController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    }

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(margin, margin, margin, margin)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return margin
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return margin
}
```

}

Hope this helps.  There probably is an easier way to ensure margins are exact, but this is one method.  Also, this code hasn't been tested for devices that allow rotating collectionviews.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` this layout does the job:

```
    let rowHeight:CGFloat = 50 // adjust as needed
    let columnCount = CGFloat(4) // adjust as needed
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (_, _) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/columnCount),
                heightDimension: .absolute(rowHeight)
            )
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: layoutSize)
            item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/columnCount)
            )
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            return section
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Note, you probably just want height dimension in the *group* to also just be the rowHeight.

Answer (score 0):

the perfect solution is to 
Using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout 
but you can easily so calculate the cell width and divided on the wanted number of columns you want

the tricky is to make the width with no fraction

```
(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
 CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
   CGFloat marginWidth = (screenWidth - collectionView.frame.size.width);


   CGFloat cellWith = (collectionView.frame.size.width - marginWidth )/3;
   cellWith= floorf(cellWith);




  CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(cellWith,cellWith);


  return retval;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a collection layout.

To make the separator visible, Set the background color of the collection view to gray.
One row per section.

Useage:

```
let layout = GridCollectionViewLayout()
layout.cellHeight = 50 // if not set, cellHeight = Collection.height/numberOfSections
layout.cellWidth = 50  // if not set, cellWidth = Collection.width/numberOfItems(inSection)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Layout:

```
import UIKit

class GridCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {


var cellWidth : CGFloat = 0
var cellHeight : CGFloat = 0
var seperator: CGFloat = 1

private var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()



override func prepare() {

    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
        return
    }

    self.cache.removeAll()



        let numberOfSections = collectionView.numberOfSections

        if cellHeight <= 0
        {
            cellHeight = (collectionView.bounds.height - seperator*CGFloat(numberOfSections-1))/CGFloat(numberOfSections)
        }

        for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {

            let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)

            let cellWidth2 : CGFloat
            if cellWidth <= 0
            {
                cellWidth2 = (collectionView.bounds.width - seperator*CGFloat(numberOfItems-1))/CGFloat(numberOfItems)
            }
            else
            {
                cellWidth2 = cellWidth
            }


            for row in 0..<numberOfItems {


                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)

                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath as IndexPath)
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: (cellWidth2+seperator)*CGFloat(row),
                                          y: (cellHeight+seperator)*CGFloat(section),
                                          width: cellWidth2,
                                          height: cellHeight)

                //row_temp.append(attributes)

                self.cache.append(attributes)
            }
            //self.itemAttributes.append(row_temp)
        }

}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else
    {
        return CGSize.zero
    }

    if (collectionView.numberOfSections <= 0)
    {
        return collectionView.bounds.size
    }

    let width:CGFloat
    if cellWidth <= 0
    {
        width = collectionView.bounds.width
    }
    else
    {
        width = cellWidth*CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))
    }

    let numberOfSections = CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfSections)
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    height += numberOfSections * cellHeight
    height += (numberOfSections - 1) * seperator



    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,It's working perfect for me,

**Follow below steps:**

**1. Define values in .h file.**

```
     #define kNoOfColumsForCollection 3
     #define kNoOfRowsForCollection 4
     #define kcellSpace 5
     #define kCollectionViewCellWidth (self.view.frame.size.width - kcellSpace*kNoOfColumsForCollection)/kNoOfColumsForCollection
     #define kCollectionViewCellHieght (self.view.frame.size.height-40- kcellSpace*kNoOfRowsForCollection)/kNoOfRowsForCollection
```

**OR**

```
  #define kNoOfColumsForCollection 3
  #define kCollectionViewCellWidthHieght (self.view.frame.size.width - 6*kNoOfColumsForCollection)/kNoOfColumsForCollection
```

**2.Add Code in collection View Layout data source methods as below,**

```
 #pragma mark Collection View Layout data source methods
// collection view with autolayout

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
 {
 return 1;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4);
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
   sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return 
 CGSizeMake(kCollectionViewCellWidth,kCollectionViewCellHieght);
 // CGSizeMake (kCollectionViewCellWidthHieght,kCollectionViewCellWidthHieght);
}
```

Hope this will be help for some one.