# iOS Orientation UICollectionView

Tags: ios, orientation, uicollectionview

My collectionView presents 20 items in landscape mode. In portrait mode, I only want 8 reusable items presented.  How can I achieve this?

When does the collectionView call collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: on the data source in order to update itself???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to force the application to change layout of the collection view when changing orientation:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

See this thread: [UICollectionView Set number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674986/uicollectionview-set-number-of-columns)

Good luck!

Comment: `-[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]` is deprecated on iOS 8, any other alternative for this?

Comment: The Apple Docs suggest: `Deprecated:Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: to make interface-based adjustments.`