# How can I create 3 columns using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a 3 columns with a UICollectionView, Here is the code I did:
I have attached a UICollectionViewFlowLayout to my UICollectionView and  I set the itemSize to be collection view's width divides by 3:

```
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor blueColor];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    double width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    width /= 3;
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(width, 100)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

But when I run it, I only see 1 item per row but the width of the item is set correctly. The right of the item is a bunch of white spaces.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Thank you.

Update:

I have tried this with minimum spacing set. But that still does not work. I only see 1 column of cells:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(160, 160)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0f;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

When I adjust the spacing values in the code, I see the spacing on the screen changes. It is just that it only layout the cell in 1 column. Instead of 2

Comment: If you log width, what does it give you?

Comment: There should be space between two UICollectionViewCell.For ex: If UICollectionView width is 320 pixel and you want 10px gap between two cells, so, you should fix the width of cell as 320-40=280/3 pixel (assuming 3 cell in one row). I assume that your first cell will start from 10 pixel inside collection view.

Comment: set the `minimumInterItemSpacing`.

Comment: @johnykumar, It's true his math is off (unless he has no spaces at all), but if he's using the default spacing (10), that wouldn't explain why he sees only one cell; he should see 2 at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating `UICollectionViewLayout` you should specify `itemSize`, `minimumInterItemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` and optionally scrolling direction using this information only collection view layout its items.

Answer (score 1):

implement the `<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>` Protocol, using this you can do

```
collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:
collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection:
collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:
collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```

refer this [How do I create a UICollectionView with column and row headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925647/how-do-i-create-a-uicollectionview-with-column-and-row-headers)

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that your trailing space layout constraint for your collection view isn't setup properly to expand itself horizontally.

In other words, the collection view is trying to tile items horizontally but doesn't have any room on the right to place additional items so it wraps to the next line.