# UINavigationBar Customization

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to implement an app and add symbols of weekdays exactly as it is done in iOS Calendar.

[image]

The first issue I've met is size. When I change the height of the navigation bar within `viewDidLoad` method it returns to its original size after appearing so I have to do the same operation in view's appearing.

The way I'm going.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height += 30
```

Then it's about other items. Once a new view controller is pushed to the navigation hierarchy Bar Buttons are created automatically. So is there an actual way to simply change their positions? Or do I have to create my own ones and add them to the navigation bar?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think that the weekday letters are part of the navigation bar, but rather of the collection view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925647/how-do-i-create-a-uicollectionview-with-column-and-row-headers

Comment: You can see the separator line that means either it is a navigation bar or the navigation bar doesn't have separator and a view with weekday symbols simply owns one.

Comment: Why don't you do it in storyboard?

Comment: You can't change UINavigationBar size in Storyboard. Only programmatically. And I'm not sure where to go so I'm asking here.

Comment: I suggest making a view underneath the navigation bar and getting rid of the bottom line of the navigation bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-ios7-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line this may help you get rid of the bottom line in the navigation bar (it's in Obj C though).

Comment: I've already got a view with weekday symbols but when I add it to the navigation bar its items are placing in wrong positions...