# Fixed number of columns in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I am creating a chess board and want to use UICollectionView to do the grid layout. The problem is, I don't know how to set the number of columns to always be 8, so as to create a 8x8 grid.

I understand that `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` can be implemented to control the size of the items, but my question is will it work across all iOS devices (iPhone 4s - iPhone 6+, iPads). From what I have seen, it looks like i need to handle the size of the cells individually by each device type.

[UICollectionView Set number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674986/uicollectionview-set-number-of-columns)

Is anyone aware of a better solution to the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView Set number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674986/uicollectionview-set-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget the UICollectionView and go the a SpriteKit game. That will leave you way more control. You can even add a Game Scene in an "ordinary" iOS app.