# Show three components in one row of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have to show three components in one row of `UICollectionView` I have written the following piece of code to manipulate `flowlayout`

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    CGSize size = flowLayout.itemSize;
    size.width = (Get_Bounds.width-40)/3;
    size.height = 135;   
    return size;

}
```

This works fine in all `iOS` devices but does not render good on `iPhone 6 Plus` it renders only two component on this device.

Comment: hi [Avnash Sharma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5945700/avinash-sharma) ,your question is duplicate check-it:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34116251/5593725

Answer (score 0):

you try that code

```
    let height = img.size.height
    let width = img.size.width
    let cellHeight = collectionView.frame.size.width/3 * height / width
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/3, height: cellHeight)
```

get device size:

```
func iPhoneScreenSizes(){
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let height = bounds.size.height

switch height {
case 480.0:
    print("iPhone 3,4")
case 568.0:
    print("iPhone 5")
case 667.0:
    print("iPhone 6")
case 736.0:
    print("iPhone 6+")

default:
    print("not an iPhone")

}
```

}

you need to create constrain outlet and manage it to device dependent

Comment: I want exactly three components in one row!!

Comment: No  i want to be dependent on the size of the screen and not anything else!

Answer (score 0):

In **sizeForItemAtIndexPath** method what you need is to give the size of the **collectionViewCell Item**.

so with this algorithm we divide collection view cell dimension by 3 and subtract 15(5 for each element) similar vice versa for height.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width/3)-15, height: (self.view.frame.size.width/3)+15)

  }
```

Comment: How does the above implementation works good for all other devices other than iPhone 6 plus? can you point that out?